# GCE : Do not mark VM as available, until disks are attached, and mounted in startup script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gce-persistent-disk

I have a startup scipt that mounts attached disks.  I tried putting sleep 10, despite that the VM is available for login BEFORE the disks are mounted!

[image]

How can I make sure the VM is available for login/green only after disks are mounted?

My startup script has this snippet for mounting the disk

```sh
# Mount the external disk --
# NOTE: if this disk is attached by this point,  all subsequent commands will fail
sleep 10;
sudo lsblk
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/disks/datadisk
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/disks/datadisk
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the behavior of the status of the VM. In fact, the status depends if the VM is already running ([status](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/get)) as "hardware" and does not depend on the startup script status or even if the SO is ready. For example the status can be `Running` (green) even if the SO crashed at boot time because of a misconfiguration.

For this specific case maybe you can try to mount the disks adding the entries to  `/etc/fstab`